# iPhone Development: nil userInfo when receiving a notification

Tags: iphone, nsnotifications

I post the notifications like this in an operation:

```
   DownloadStatus * status = [[DownloadStatus alloc] init];
   [status setMessage: @"Download started"];
   [status setStarted];
   [status setCompleteSize: [filesize intValue]];
   [userInfo setValue:status forKey:@"state"];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
       postNotificationName:[targetURL absoluteString]
       object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
   [status release];
```

DownloadStatus is an object that contains some information abou the download that is being currently downloaded. userInfo is a property of the object that has been initialized in the init part and is kept for the complete duration of the operation. It is created so:

```
 NSDictionary * userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:targetURL 
                                                             forKey:@"state"];
```

"targetURL" is a NSString, I use this just to make sure everything is working fine. When I receive the event - I registered like this:

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
       addObserver:self selector:@selector(downloadStatusUpdate:) 
       name:videoUrl 
       object:nil];
```

Here "videoUrl" is a string that contains the url being downloaded, so that I will receive notification about an url I'm waiting to see downloaded.

The selector is implemented like this:

```
   - (void) downloadStatusUpdate:(NSNotification*) note   {

     NSDictionary * ui = note.userInfo; // Tried also [note userInfo]

     if ( ui == nil ) {
         DLog(@"Received an update message without userInfo!");
         return;
     }
     DownloadStatus * state = [[ui allValues] objectAtIndex:0];
     if ( state == nil ) {
         DLog(@"Received notification without state!");
         return;
     }
     DLog(@"Status message: %@", state.message);
     [state release], state = nil;
     [ui release], ui = nil;   }
```

But this selector always receives a null userInfo. What am I doing wrong?

MrWHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way or another, you seem to be initialising your userInfo object incorrectly. The line as given:

```
NSDictionary * userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:targetURL 
                                                        forKey:@"state"];
```

Would create an autoreleased NSDictionary and store it to a local variable. The value would not be propagated up to your member variable.

Supposing that's a snippet, followed by e.g.

```
self.userInfo = userInfo;
```

to assign the local to the member, retaining it at the same time, then your code should generate an exception at this line:

```
[userInfo setValue:status forKey:@"state"];
```

Since it attempts to mutate an immutable object. It's therefore much more likely that the value of userInfo isn't stored and you're messaging nil at that point.

So, I would think that — assuming you have userInfo declared as a 'retain' type property, you want to replace:

```
NSDictionary * userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:targetURL 
                                                        forKey:@"state"];
```

With:

```
self.userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:targetURL 
                                                        forKey:@"state"];
```

Comment: Thanks you! That was it - it looks obvious now, of course I couldn't see it when I just looked at the code. Thank you for your help!